# Can anyone explain one inequality regarding random variables constructed from distribution function?

Tags: probability

Suppose $F:R\rightarrow[0, 1]$ be a distribution function(right continuous). Then it is possible to construct a measure space ([0,1], B([0, 1]), Leb) where B([0, 1]) is the borel sigma algebra on the real interval [0,1] and Leb is the legbesgue measure with following two random variables

$$X^+(\omega):=\inf\{z:F(z)>\omega\}=\sup\{y:F(y)\le \omega\}$$

$$X^-(\omega):=\inf\{z:F(z)\ge \omega\}=\sup\{y:F(y)<\omega\} $$

My book states the following.

> By the right-continuity, $F(X^{-}(\omega)) \ge \omega$.

Why is this true? And what does this have to do with right continuity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z_0=X^{-}(\omega)$. Then using properties of infima, there is a sequence $\{z_n\}$ in the set $\{z:F(z)\geq \omega\}$ such that $z_n$ decreases to $z_0$. Since $F$ is right continuous, it then follows that
$$ F(z_0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}F(z_n)\geq \omega$$
since $F(z_n)\geq \omega$ for all $n$.

Comment: You mean >= omega?

Comment: Yes, good point.

Answer (score 1):

We have the definition $X^-(\omega):=\inf\{z:F(z)\ge \omega\}$ where $F:\Bbb R\mapsto[0;1]$ is right continuous.

Then $X^-(\omega)$ is the largest lowerbound on the set of real numbers where the given condition holds; the set of $z\in\Bbb R$, where $F(z)\geq\omega$.   Right continuity of $F$ and the nonstrict inequality of the condition means that the lower boundary is included in the set. $$X^-(\omega)\in\{z:F(z)\ge \omega\}$$

Therefore $F(X^-(\omega))\ge \omega$